# .load in jQuery not loading cfcharts in IE6

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I am trying to dynamically load the contents of a div tag with a .cfm page that contains a cfchart in png format. When the user clicks on a link, I am using the load function to put the .cfm page into the div.

```
$("#bank").bind("click", function(){
    $("#chartx").load("bank.cfm");
});
```

I can get this to come up perfectly in Firefox, but not in IE6. It gives no error messages.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this? I'm having similar issues with CF8 and IE.

Answer (score 3):

Weirdest thing, but the cfdebug information in the classic style appended on the page is what causes it to break.

Comment: Ah yes, you have to disable ColdFusion Debugging output on AJAX requested pages or you get a bunch of junk on your page. You can disable it per page with the cfsetting tag.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried jQuery.get? Maybe something like:

```
$("#bank").bind("click", function(){
    $.get("bank.cfm", function(data){
        $("#chartx").html(data);
    });
});
```

It's not as clean but it's more specific. Maybe it will take a different course from whatever is breaking.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, so that's what it was. I was going to say that sometimes on some computers if you have IE security settings set too high, AJAX calls that load special components into the page sometimes don't work.